# How to call int or string from subclass in Java

Tags: java, class, call, subclass

I have class **ClassifierModule**  and subclass **ClassifierRunnable**. There are some ints (e.g. `int r =`) and string (`String csvLine =`) in ClassifierRunnable. How to call either `int` or `string` in ClassifierModule class?

Here is my code:

```
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

            public ClassifierModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                super(reactContext);
                appState = ((MainApplication)reactContext.getApplicationContext());
            }     

            // ---------------------------------------------------------
            // React Native Module methods
            // Required by ReactContextBaseJavaModule

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "Classifier";
            }

public class ClassifierRunnable implements Runnable {


            public ClassifierRunnable(double[][] buffer) {
                rawBuffer = buffer;
                PSD = new double[NUM_CHANNELS][nbBins];
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (noisePresent(rawBuffer)) {
                    Log.w("ConcentrationTracker", "noise");

                    return;
                }

                else if(isTracking) {
                    getSmoothPSD(rawBuffer);

                    bandMeans = bandExtractor.extract1D(PSD);

                    // Concentration algorithm goes here
                    int score = measureRatio(bandMeans);

                    Log.w("ConcentrationTracker", "Concentration score" + score);

                    sendEvent("CONCENTRATION_SCORE", score);
                }

                else if(isLogging) {
                    getSmoothPSD(rawBuffer);

                    bandMeans = bandExtractor.extract1D(PSD);

                    int a = measureAlpha(bandMeans);
                    int b = measureBeta(bandMeans);
                    int d = measureDelta(bandMeans);
                    int t = measureTheta(bandMeans);
                    int r = measureRatio(bandMeans);

                    String csvLine = a + "," + b + "," + d + "," + t + "," + r;

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can't. A base class knows nothing about its subclasses. And this is not a missing language feature, it's a basic principle of OOP.

Comment: Can't I send it as event?

Comment: You probably can use events, but why not add the variable to the base class?

Comment: I tried to do that, but constructor of base class is different and code didn't work at all.

Comment: Looking at your code, `ClassifierModule` is **not** a subclass of `ClassifierRunnable` (it's probably a nested class -- but hard to tell, as crucial parts are missing)

Comment: You're right. ClassifierModule is outer class and ClassifierRunnable is inner class.